# Algorithmically distribute colors of balls in a row as evenly as possible?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose I have 1 red ball, 2 green balls, 4 blue balls, 8 yellow balls, . . ., 2^(n-1) balls of n-th color.

What would be an algorithm that would provide me with an ideally even distribution of colors? For the sake of how I am applying this problem, the first and last positions in this row are adjacent. Therefore, one might consider this "row" of balls to be in a circular shape.

For n = 2, I'd place the red ball first, then the two green balls. Remember that the third ball is considered to be adjacent to the first, therefore saying "green, then red, then green," while seemingly a better solution, is equivalent.

For n = 3, I might (I am pretty this is an ideal distribution, but not 100%) start with the red ball, place a blue ball, then a green ball, then a blue ball, then the two remaining green balls. RBGBGBB.

I am looking at some form of recursion, but I just can't pin this problem down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I just figured it out while taking a toilet break from programming.

It is indeed recursive:

Alternate any color except the largest quantity, followed by the largest quantity color. You will end up with the largest quantity color twice in a row at the end. Solve recursively for the series of "any color except the largest quantity" series.

For example with n=3.

Take any color (but not blue), then blue, then any color, then blue, then any color, then two blue.

This "any color but not blue" series is now a "row" of 3 when you discount the blue balls which can be reduced to n=2.